# How can I use 2 different sizes of the same font in one cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, fonts

For instance, I want to list a person's name in one size font, and his graduation year ('14) in a smaller font.

Comment: Yopu can do this manually by carefully selecting the year within the cell or formula bar and using the limited font formatting options or with some degree of automation within VBA using `ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=<an index point>, Length:=4).Font`

Answer (score 1):

Type the name and year in the cell using one of the two font sizes you want.  In the bar at the top that displays what you typed highlight the portion you want to re-size.  Then either right click and select the new font size or go to the Home, Font section and select it.